# expanding a div to reveal overflow on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking at this example on [this website](http://www.storenvy.com/products/3137847-wool-pencil-skirts). I wanted to create an effect similar like that where you have a <div> that has some <p> in it and there's a button to show the full expanded description. I've analyzed the html and it looks like this:

```
<div class="product-description">
   <div class="desc-wrap" itemprop="description">
      <p>Material: wool
         <br>6 Colors: Black, Yellow, Gray, Wine Red, Green, Navy Blue
         <br>Size: One size only
         <br>Recommended for size SMALL
         <br>It has been noted by customers that these skirts are short.
         <br>*Please check the measurement picture for sizing information. There are no refunds on orders that were messed up on your behalf.
      </p>
      <p>Note: Due to the difference between different monitors, the color may be off a tiny bit.</p>
      <p>WORLDWIDE SHIPPING!
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="desc-fade"></div>
   <div class="open-link" style="display: block;"><a href="javascript:;">Expand Full Description</a></div>
</div>
```

I assume that there's a javascript function that expands the box on click. But what is that? How do I reproduce this same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example for exectly what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/kedem/D9NCP/

css:

```
    .product-description {
        height:150px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position:relative;
    }
    .product-description.open {
        height:auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        position:relative;
    }
    .desc-fade {
        width: 200%;
        margin-left: -50%;
        height: 30px;
        background: #fff;
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 30px #fff;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 30px #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px 30px #fff;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms, 1s;
        -moz-transition: opacity 250ms, 1s;
        -o-transition: opacity 250ms, 1s;
        transition: opacity 250ms, 1s;
    }
    .open-link {
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 15px;
        z-index:2;
    }
```

jquery:

```
     $(function () {
        var wrapHeight = $(".product-description .desc-wrap").height();
        var descHeight = $(".product-description").height();

        if (wrapHeight <= descHeight) {
            $(".product-description .desc-fade").hide();
            $(".product-description .open-link").hide();
        }

        $(".product-description .open-link").click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $(".product-description .desc-fade").hide();
            $(".product-description").animate({
                height: wrapHeight
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hello How would you do this for two divs next to each other on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM inspector, it will help you understanding the trick. First they use a constant height for the container. Onclick remove the text and expand the div by setting a bigger height.

However, we have to determine the total height of the div so we shouldn't hide the expanded part from the start

http://jsfiddle.net/2SMF2/2/

```
$('.expand').click(function () {
     $('#test').removeClass('collapsed', 'fast')
     $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this works for you? 
[JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bEzBy/)

HTML

```
<div class="div-wrapper">
    <div class="hider">
        <p>Here goes your text that is partially shown Here goes your text that is partially shown Here goes your text that is partially shown Here goes your text that is partially shown Here goes your text that is partially shown Here goes your text that is partially shown Here goes your text that is partially shown Here goes your text that is partially shown Here goes your text that is partially shown Here goes your text that is partially shown Here goes your text that is partially shown Here goes your text that is partially shown </p>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="open-link">Show all</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* this first one is not necesary */
.div-wrapper {
    width:300px;
    border:solid 1px #000;
}

.div-wrapper>.hider {
    height: 100px;
    transition: ease-in-out all 0.2s;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.open-link').click(function(e) {
       var $wrapper = $(this).parent().find('.hider');
       $wrapper.css('height',$wrapper.find('p').height());
       $(this).remove();
    })
});
```

let me know if it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/VvBRh/

What I have done:

```
$('.open-link a').click(function(){

     if($(".desc-wrap").css("height") == "60px") {

        //Find auto height of div and save it

        $('.desc-wrap').css('height', 'auto');
        var autoHeight = $('.desc-wrap').height();

        //Revert back to 2 lines

        $('.desc-wrap').css('height', '60px');

        //Animate to the saved autoHeight

        $(".desc-wrap").animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000);

    } else {

        //Shrink back to 2 lines (you can remove this if you want)

      $(".desc-wrap").animate({height: "60px"}, 1000);

    }
    return false;
});
```

You will also need to add a little css to get inital settings:

```
.desc-wrap { height: 60px; overflow: hidden }
```

I'm sure this could be more elegant, and you could derive the height of 2 lines instead of fixed px, but I'll leave that up to you to decide ;)

Comment: Hello How would you do this for two divs next to each other on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $divView = $('div.view');
    var innerHeight = $divView.removeClass('view').height();
    $divView.addClass('view');

    $('div.slide').click(function() {
        $('div.view').animate({
          height: (($divView.height() == 110)? innerHeight  : "110px")
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
<style>
.view{
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 110px;

}
.total{
border:1px solid;
/*height:130px;
overflow-y:auto;*/
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="total">
<div class="view">
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
</div>
<div class="slide" style="cursor: pointer;">Show/Hide</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```